# Smart Suggest - jQuery help

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I purchased the following jQuery widget from CodeCanyon - http://jamesskidmore.com/scripts/smartsuggest/ and the only thing missing in the widget is a keyup/keydown handler to highlight the selections in the list.

I am not very familiar with jQuery itself and am wondering if anyone would be able to do this?

I managed to bind the event but have no idea on how to handle the navigation:

```
   $('#searchField').bind("keydown.autocomplete",function(c){
    switch(c.keyCode) {
    case 38: // UP
        alert('Keyup');
        break;
    case 40: // DOWN
        alert('Keydown');
        break;
    }

   });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dropdown list has no active state (only css `:hover`), so you'll have to add that too. You'd also have to add the enter event, so simulate a mouseclick on the `:hover` element.

Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/rudiedirkx/PWE2S/

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer - your help provided sufficient information for me to customise the script and get it working.